# ModalDropdown width issue in React Native

Tags: ios, css, react-native

I am working on a React Native application. I am testing it os IOS I have used ModalDropdown in it, the code of ModalDropdown is:

```
<ModalDropdown
        style={{display:"flex", justifyContent:"flex-start",fontSize:16, height:35, width:"99%", borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderRadius:50, paddingTop:4, paddingLeft:14, marginLeft:6, paddingRight:14}}
        textStyle={{color:"grey", fontSize:16}}
        dropdownStyle={{width:"80%"}}
        dropdownTextStyle={{color:"gray", fontSize:16}}
        options={this.state.checklists}
        onSelect={(value) => this.onChangeTextPress(value)}
        />
```

This shows the drop down like this:

[image]
I want the drop down to be align with the "Please select..." textbox. I have tried changing the width of "dropdownstyle" but this does not work on different devices like iPhone, iPad. How can i make this work fine on all devices.

Comment: Are you saying that the width does not change in iOS?

Comment: no, it does change, but currently it is working well on iPhone but not on iPad

Comment: Could you try this? `dropdownStyle={{width: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 5) * 4 }}`

Comment: I added my comments as an answer. Would you please choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the screen width value does not allow a percentage value, use the entire screen width divided.

```js
dropdownStyle={{width: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 5) * 4 }}
```